# Installing Windows after Ubuntu without live USB or CD

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-7, live-usb

I have a acer aspire es15 with preinstalled windows 10.. but i accidently deleted windows and installed ubuntu 14.04 now can I install windows 7 without deleting ubuntu as dual boot without using a live usb??
I heard of EasyBCD but does it work???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must carefully select the partitions you use for the Windows install to ensure you do not overwrite any partition required by the other OS.  Then, once you have installed Windows you must boot Ubuntu from a USB drive/stick.  There, you need to install Boot Repair on the USB drive Ubuntu is on and have it repair the Ubuntu Grub bootloader which will detect the Windows partition and included it in the boot options presented at normal boot up.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair - You are best to use the "Advanced Options" selection so you can select which things you want to ensure happen, such as having one of the two OS's boot as the primary OS (so that if you install a Windows or Ubuntu update when it reboots you it will load that OS when it restarts in case you are away from the computer).

Comment: You can use an SD, MicroSD or other card to load Ubuntu onto and boot from it, possibly removing a lack of USB drive.  Need only a 6GB or larger SD/MicroSD/MMC/etc card and a card reader, which your computer may already have and you can boot from.

Comment: can you tell me how to create a live USB without downloading anything

Comment: If you still have the ubuntu iso file then you should copy it into your Ubunutu user home location "/home/(your name)/"  Then open a terminal and type dd if=/home/(user name)/"(ubuntu iso exact name)" of=/dev/(location of your usb drive).  The location of your USB drive can be found using the "Disks" program found in the Accessories section of your start button programs, where if you click your USB drive it will show below it "Device: /dev/(location of your usb drive)".  You should make certain your usb drive is not mounted in the Disks program by clicking the square stop button.

Comment: but i dont have the iso file thats why i am asking this

Comment: You may consider downloading another copy of the Ubuntu iso.  Then the above by me will work / can be used.  Ubuntu Mate is fairly small (to make the download faster) and provides the disk program automatically.

Comment: In my answer near the top (when using the USB version) make sure you choose to "Try" the OS (where , rather than installing the OS you can run the live OS and install other software like the disks manager).  In case the Disks program was not installed automatically simply open a terminal window and enter "sudo apt-get update" then "sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility" which will install it.